# How to pass no value into a VF custom search controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am sure this is a very basic question, but the solution I am thinking of does not seem to be efficient, so I was wandering if someone could point me in the right direction.
I am building a custom VF page that will perform a search on Contact.In total I have about 7 fields that can be used to narrow the contact record. For simplicity, for now I am trying to simply search on First and Last name. The issue I am having is that if one of the fields is not populated, my search is considering that as an empty sting which is used in the search. For example, if I have 2 contacts (James Bond, Jeannie Bond), if both firstName and lastName are populated all works great. But if I populate only last name, then I get no results. One way to account for this is to run different if statements checking which fields are populated. I do have 7, which can have multiple scenarios. Is there a better way to account for this than using if statements to check which fields are populated and adjust the query to match?
 This is what I have:

```
public class CasSearchCon {
public String pageMessage {get;private set;}
public String firstName {get;set;}
public String lastName {get;set;}
public String caseNumber {get;set;}
public String street {get;set;}
public String city {get;set;}
public String state {get;set;}
public String zip {get;set;}
public String email {get;set;}

public list<Contact> contactResult {get;set;} 


public void search(){
    contactResult = new List<Contact>();
    contactResult = [Select id, FirstName, LastName from Contact where LastName=:lastName and FirstName =:firstName];


    System.debug('ReturnedContact :' +contactResult);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your SOQL filter criteria. AND logic requires all filters to be matched. OR logic means that only one needs to be matched. So your query should look as follows:

```
[Select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contact where LastName=:lastName OR FirstName =:firstName]
```

Comment: OMG, I need more coffee. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Yep! Happy coding :-)